# How to send an SSO SAML assertion to Sharepoint Online to get FedAuth and rtFa cookies?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sso, saml

My goal is to get a binary security token for Office365 so that I can generate fedauth/rtfa cookies to access Sharepoint Online REST/Soap Web Services.

I have PingFederate linked to my office365 azure, so that users must log into PingFederate in order to access my sharepoint online instance.

I have generated a SAML1.1 assertion using PingFederate SSO. Here is a scrubbed version:

```
<saml:Assertion xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:assertion"
                AssertionID="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
                IssueInstant="2018-01-31T20:22:02.704Z"
                Issuer="https://pingfederation.nickexample.com"
                MajorVersion="1"
                MinorVersion="1">
    <saml:Conditions NotBefore="2018-01-31T20:17:02.704Z" NotOnOrAfter="2018-01-31T20:27:02.704Z">
        <saml:AudienceRestrictionCondition>
            <saml:Audience>urn:federation:MicrosoftOnline</saml:Audience>
        </saml:AudienceRestrictionCondition>
    </saml:Conditions>
    <saml:AuthenticationStatement AuthenticationInstant="2018-01-31T20:22:02.704Z"
                                  AuthenticationMethod="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:am:unspecified">
        <saml:Subject>
            <saml:NameIdentifier Format="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/claims/UPN">nick@nickexample.com
            </saml:NameIdentifier>
            <saml:SubjectConfirmation>
                <saml:ConfirmationMethod>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:cm:bearer</saml:ConfirmationMethod>
            </saml:SubjectConfirmation>
        </saml:Subject>
    </saml:AuthenticationStatement>
    <saml:AttributeStatement>
        <saml:Subject>
            <saml:NameIdentifier Format="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/claims/UPN">nick@nickexample.com
            </saml:NameIdentifier>
            <saml:SubjectConfirmation>
                <saml:ConfirmationMethod>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:cm:bearer</saml:ConfirmationMethod>
            </saml:SubjectConfirmation>
        </saml:Subject>
        <saml:Attribute AttributeName="UPN" AttributeNamespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/claims">
            <saml:AttributeValue>nick@nick-example.com</saml:AttributeValue>
        </saml:Attribute>
        <saml:Attribute AttributeName="ImmutableID"
                        AttributeNamespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/LiveID/Federation/2008/05">
            <saml:AttributeValue>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXx</saml:AttributeValue>
        </saml:Attribute>
    </saml:AttributeStatement>
    <ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <ds:SignedInfo>
            <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
            <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
            <ds:Reference URI="#xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx">
                <ds:Transforms>
                    <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/>
                    <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
                </ds:Transforms>
                <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
                <ds:DigestValue>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</ds:DigestValue>
            </ds:Reference>
        </ds:SignedInfo>
        <ds:SignatureValue>
            xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
            xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
            xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
            xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
        </ds:SignatureValue>
        <ds:KeyInfo>
            <ds:X509Data>
                <ds:X509Certificate>
                    xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
                    xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
                    xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
                    xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
                    xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
                    xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
                    xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
                    xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
                    xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
                    xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
                    xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
                    xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
                    xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
                    xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
                    xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
                    xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
                    xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
                    xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
                    xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
                    xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
                    xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
                    xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
                    xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
                    xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
                    xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
                    xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
                    xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
                    xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
                    xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
                    xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
                    xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
                    xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
                    xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx=
                </ds:X509Certificate>
            </ds:X509Data>
            <ds:KeyValue>
                <ds:RSAKeyValue>
                    <ds:Modulus>
                        xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
                        xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
                        xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
                        xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
                        xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
                    </ds:Modulus>
                    <ds:Exponent>AQAB</ds:Exponent>
                </ds:RSAKeyValue>
            </ds:KeyValue>
        </ds:KeyInfo>
    </ds:Signature>
</saml:Assertion>
```

I send that saml assertion to the https://login.microsoftonline.com/login.srf endpoint

```
POST: https://login.microsoftonline.com/login.srf

Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Form params:

    wa = wsignin1.0

    wresult = (saml1.1 assertion xml)
```

I do not get an error, but I am being presented with the "Sign in" HTML page as the response:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="ltr" class="" lang="en">
<head>
<title>Sign in to your account</title>
...
```

I am pretty sure this same thing worked for ADFS. Does it only work for ADFS not PingFederate or other third-party SSOs?
Am I missing a step, or misunderstanding how this works?

Comment: I can get the cookies.
How can I use it login shareoint online on browser.
Thank you.

Comment: if you are in the browser, log in the normal way using the microsoft login url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've also spent a lot of time trying to figuring this one out, so in case anyone reads this, this might help.

Following [the tutorial here](http://www.sharepoint-insight.com/2016/03/21/step-by-step-sharepoint-online-authentiaction-process-via-http-protocol/) the SAML message has to be wrapped in a SOAP message and then has to be sent to https://login.microsoftonline.com/RST2.srf as in step 10. There is also an example of how the full token shall look like.

This endpoint also gave me more useful error messages like `"MinorVersion missing"`. However, I could not get this to work as my token was SAML 2.0 and the endpoint at the end gave me the message that it only understands 1.1.

UPDATE:

The previously linked tutorial was not correct. Step 10 was broken. [Better tutorial that uses powershell](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/sharepointdevelopersupport/2018/02/07/sharepoint-online-active-authentication/) actually has the completely generic steps for getting login cookies for SharePoint Online even if you are using Ping identity.

But as noted above, the thing that was majorly wrong with the op's attempt was the login.microsoft.com endpoint he was using. Must use https://login.microsoftonline.com/RST2.srf instead of login.srf

Comment: woah cool! awesome samya we will try this.

Comment: i get stuck on step `10. POST following XML to https://login.microsoftonline.com/RST2.srf` - he says to "extract the saml assertion" but then he says to send the RST response XML to the RST2.srf. that doesn't sound right. I was expecting a POST to `http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust/RST/Issue`

Comment: I have a fully working HTTP auth of ADFS backed sharepoint online working fine. 
But it seems like the main tip here is to try the RST2.srf endpoint instead of the one i was using `/login.srf`. Trying that now.

Comment: I updated this ticket with some fresh documentation created by sharepoint engineering feb 2018 as a result of my and other's complaining about lack of documentation on this. It is in powershell but you can easily extract the HTTP calls needed. I updated the answer with the link. Marking as answer because finally this works.

Answer (score 1):

While following [the tutorial here](http://www.sharepoint-insight.com/2016/03/21/step-by-step-sharepoint-online-authentiaction-process-via-http-protocol/), I was also stuck at step 10. But I found the solution on that.

**Solution:**

Extract the **saml:Assertion** tag from the step 8 response.
Then, instead of POSTing (step 8 XML response) to https://login.microsoftonline.com/RST2.srf, POST the below XLM to https://login.microsoftonline.com/extSTS.srf

Before POSTing, please change the saml:Assertion and a:Address tags with actual values.

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"
      xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"
      xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
  <s:Header>
    <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust/RST/Issue</a:Action>
    <a:ReplyTo>
      <a:Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</a:Address>
    </a:ReplyTo>
    <a:To s:mustUnderstand="1">https://login.microsoftonline.com/extSTS.srf</a:To>
    <o:Security s:mustUnderstand="1"
       xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">

      <saml:Assertion MajorVersion="1" MinorVersion="1"....</saml:Assertion>

    </o:Security>
  </s:Header>
  <s:Body>
    <t:RequestSecurityToken xmlns:t="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust">
      <wsp:AppliesTo xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy">
        <a:EndpointReference>

          <a:Address>{your-domain}.sharepoint.com</a:Address>

        </a:EndpointReference>
      </wsp:AppliesTo>
      <t:KeyType>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/NoProofKey</t:KeyType>
      <t:RequestType>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust/Issue</t:RequestType>
      <t:TokenType>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:assertion</t:TokenType>
    </t:RequestSecurityToken>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```